# Jquery .find.animate to break and repeat

Tags: jquery

I have the following jquery function that aimates my text. Basically it finds all the elements I ask it to and it animates them. The problem is, as you can see, is that it find ALL the elements at once and animate them all simultaneously. I want each element(h2, h3 and span) to be animated separately from one another.

Any suggestions? Maybe some kind of a break between the .find commands?
Thanks!

```
      $nextSlide.find('div.ei-title > h2')
                      .css( 'margin-right', 50 + 'px' )
                      .stop()
                      .delay( this.options.speed * this.options.titlesFactor )
                      .animate({ marginRight : 0 + 'px', opacity : 1 }, this.options.titlespeed, this.options.titleeasing )
                      .end()
                      .find('div.ei-title > h3')
                      .css( 'margin-right', -50 + 'px' )
                      .stop()
                      .delay( this.options.speed * this.options.titlesFactor )
                      .animate({ marginRight : 0 + 'px', opacity : 1 }, this.options.titlespeed, this.options.titleeasing )
                      .end()
                      .find('div.ei-title > span.custom1')
                      .css( 'margin-right', -50 + 'px' )
                      .stop()
                      .delay( this.options.speed * this.options.titlesFactor )
                      .animate({ marginRight : 0 + 'px', opacity : 1 }, this.options.titlespeed, this.options.titleeasing )
                      .end
                      .find('div.ei-title > span.custom2')
                      .css( 'margin-right', -50 + 'px' )
                      .stop()
                      .delay( this.options.speed * this.options.titlesFactor )
                      .animate({ marginRight : 0 + 'px', opacity : 1 }, this.options.titlespeed, this.options.titleeasing )
                      .end
```

Comment: Are you saying that you don't want them to fire all at once, or that you'd prefer them to fire `one-after-another` in succession, I.E. one starts, then finished, on finish the next starts. OR do you want just a small delay between when the animations fire, regardless of if the previous animation has completed?

Comment: I want the next one to start when the previous one has completely finished..."one-after-another in succession"...

Answer (score 0):

```
$nextSlide.find('div.ei-title > h2')
  .css( 'margin-right', 50 + 'px' )
  .stop()
  .delay( this.options.speed * this.options.titlesFactor )
  .animate({ marginRight : 0 + 'px', opacity : 1 }, this.options.titlespeed, this.options.titleeasing, function(){
    $nextSlide.find('div.ei-title > h3')
      .css( 'margin-right', -50 + 'px' )
      .stop()
      .delay( this.options.speed * this.options.titlesFactor )
      .animate({ marginRight : 0 + 'px', opacity : 1 }, this.options.titlespeed, this.options.titleeasing, function(){
        $nextSlide.find('div.ei-title > span.custom1')
          .css( 'margin-right', -50 + 'px' )
          .stop()
          .delay( this.options.speed * this.options.titlesFactor )
          .animate({ marginRight : 0 + 'px', opacity : 1 }, this.options.titlespeed, this.options.titleeasing, function(){
            $nextSlide.find('div.ei-title > span.custom2')
              .css( 'margin-right', -50 + 'px' )
              .stop()
              .delay( this.options.speed * this.options.titlesFactor )
              .animate({ marginRight : 0 + 'px', opacity : 1 }, this.options.titlespeed, this.options.titleeasing )
          });
      });
  });
```

For the purpose of this code, we must use an identifier of the object we wish to apply filters against. We cannot simply use $(this) as a reference in the callback. Based on your code, it looks as if `$nextSlide` has a reference to the object we're filtering against. For this purpose, we've used `$nextSlide` as the reference object in the `callback function` of the animation. We also refer to the callback as the `onComplete` event of the `animate function`.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but it does not seem to animate the child/nested functions(the h3 and span text)